# Angular material 2 datepicker with [ngmodel]

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, datepicker, material-design

I am trying to bind my date property to mat-datepicker's input as part of a reactive form group. All of my methods didn't work, as my submit button is set to disabled unless the form is valid:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker1" placeholder="Start Date" formControlName="startingDate" required>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #datepicker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Component.ts:

```
start: Date.now()
startDate: "1/1/2018"
this.ShiftForm = new FormGroup({
  startingDate: new FormControl(this.startDate),
  startTime: new FormControl(),
  endingDate: new FormControl(this.endDate),
  endTime: new FormControl(),
});
```

Methods which didn't work:

1. Adding `[(ngModel)]="startDate"` to input field
2. Adding `[ngModel]="startDate"` to input field
3. Preloading the formControl with the value: `startingDate: new FormControl(this.startDate),`

Methods which partially but not satisfyingly worked:

1. Adding `[value]="startDate"` to input field: date showed but not read by the Reactive Form, meaning my submit button remains disabled as the form is not valid. To make it valid, I have to set the date manually (typing or using the datepicker)
2. Adding `[ngModel]="startDate"` while removing `[matDatepicker]="datepicker1"` from the input field: date showed but removing the access to the datepicker.

All I need is the [ngModel] to work as it should so the Reactive Form reads it.

Help much much appreciated!

**EDIT**
This is my formGroup:

```
this.ShiftForm = new FormGroup({
  startingDate: new FormControl(this.startDate),
  startTime: new FormControl(),
  endingDate: new FormControl(this.endDate),
  endTime: new FormControl(),
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="ShiftForm" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker1" placeholder="Start Date" [formControlName]="startingDate" required>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #datepicker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
..
..
..
</form>
```

This is the Error I get now:

> Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Angular provides two ways of using forms: [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You're mixing those two up, while you should choose which one you want to use. The docs can guide you in this choice.

Should you choose template-driven, you can use `[(ngModel)]` (like your method 1).

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker1" placeholder="Start Date" [(ngModel)]="startDate" required>

startDate = new Date();
```

Choose reactive and you can use `[formControl]` with a `FormControl` in your controller (like your method 3).

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker1" placeholder="Start Date" [formControl]="startDate">

startDate = new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.Required);
// Use `startDate.value` to get the value of the control
```

Never use `[value]` if you don't know what you're doing or it will give you unexpected results.

Comment: I tried `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker1" placeholder="Start Date" [formControlName]="startDate">` But got an error: `Cannot find control with name: '1/2/2018'`

Comment: You’re using formControlName while you should use formControl, unless you’re using a FormGroup. Then assign a FormControl to startDate in your controller like I posted. Check the guide on reactive forms I linked to, it has lots of examples.

Comment: The wierd part is that it iis a part of a FormGroup.. I edited the code above

Comment: Remove the `[]`s from your formControlName binding. It’s now trying to bind to the controller property `startingDate`, which does not exist. You need to bind it to a string of the FormControls name: either `formControlName="startingDate"` or `[formControlName]="'startingDate'"`.

Comment: Which gets me back to step 1: with this setup, for some reason, the value doesn't show

Comment: And I made sure `this.startDate` is in the correct format: `this.startDate = moment(data.start).format('M/D/YYYY');` (used to be: `this.startDate = moment(data.start).format('l');`

Comment: The Material datepicker requires a javascript Date object, not a text formatted date. You could use `moment(data.start).toDate()`.